# image not appearing in browser

Tags: html, image, browser

This should be so easy, but I'm missing something? somewhere?

I create an html script (test.html) located on a remote server.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <title>Testing IMG</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <img src="img/ErrorTracking.png" alt="Error Tracking" height="180" width="860">
 </body>

 </html>
```

File Structure
[image: File locations]

I've double checked and ErrorTracking.png is in fact the name of the image.
[image: img contents]

When I'm in my local browser and try to view the image it doesn't appear.
[image: browser view]

What am I missing? I've spent way to long on this simple task.

Comment: Where is the image actually stored... Im assuming its your file path..

Comment: Everything looks good to me, maybe try double checking your path or include the full path?

Comment: I've tried the full path as well. I'm thinking it has something to do with the image being located on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, relative to your test.html, is the image in a folder called `img`? Also, check the case, make sure you capitalized the file name and directory correctly.

If the html file is there, you should be able to take your html url:

`http://www.yoursite.com/somewhere/test.html`

and swap out the file name with `img/ErrorTracking.png` like this:

`http://www.yoursite.com/somewhere/img/ErrorTracking.png`

If that URL doesn't show the image when visiting it in your browser, the image is in the wrong location.

Comment: That solved it! I had a symbolic link to the html, but not to the img. I referred to the image as if it were with the symbolic link with in the html(which it wasn't) and therefore the html couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `/` or `~/` in your image source.

```
<img src="/img/ErrorTracking.png" alt="Error Tracking" height="180" width="860">
```

Check out [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/htmlweb.html) link for more details on urls in html.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
<img src="/img/ErrorTracking.png" alt="Error Tracking" height="180" width="860">
```

Comment: Still nothing. Same big blank as before.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<img src="~/img/ErrorTracking.png" alt="Error Tracking" height="180" width="860">
```

if that doesnt helps

```
<img src="/img/ErrorTracking.png" alt="Error Tracking" height="180" width="860">
```

Comment: I just tried the tilde. Nothing changed! This is driving me crazy!